# Erro ao compilar App com Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

Estou tendo alguns problemas para compilar meu projeto no `Xamarin no VS2015`.

> Error java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>   NavegacaoIntent

Como estou iniciando, o meu aplicativo só possui 2 botões e duas telas, ou seja, não há ainda outros componentes instalados. Eu simplesmente tentei executar a aplicação no meu emulador e no meu dispositivo (smartphone pessoal) e o erro ocorre.

Comment: Veja uma solução aqui : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457947/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion-error-in-xamarin-studio. Caso tenha dificuldade em entender faço uma tradução.

Comment: Jovem, qual a versão do Java que você tem instalada?